# Ionic 2 cordova InAppBrowser browser.close() is not a function

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am integrating a payment gateway in my ionic app in which i am using node js on the server side. On a click of button i am redirecting user to the payment gateway page using ionic native inAppBrowser after which i am listening to url events. When the payment is successful then the browser will redirect to success url else it will redirect to failed url. Based on this i am handling the UI in the app. My problem is when i listen to the success/failed url and call the **close browser** event i get this error.

> Uncaught TypeError: this.browser.close is not a function

I have also tried hide() method but i get the same error.
Following is my code.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { InAppBrowser, InAppBrowserEvent } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  event : any;
  browser:any;
  failed : boolean = false;
  success : boolean = false;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private http: Http,private iab: InAppBrowser) {

  }

  payment(){
    this.browser = this.iab.create('http://192.168.0.59:3000/post').on("loadstop")
     .subscribe((ev: InAppBrowserEvent) => {

              if(ev.url == "http://192.168.0.59:3000/failure"){
                console.log("payment failed");
                this.failed = true;
                this.closeBrowser();
              }else if(ev.url == "http://192.168.0.59:3000/success"){
                console.log("payment success");
                this.success = true;
              }

          });

      }

      closeBrowser(){
        this.browser.close();
      }

    }
```

I am also testing the app on a real device so there isn't any cordova or platform issue...Please tell me what mistake i am making.
A proper description with the answer will be quite helpful for my future references.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding following line inside constructor:

```
this.browser = this.iab.create('http://192.168.0.59:3000/post');
```

You can also use const for that purpose like:

```
const browser = this.iab.create('http://192.168.0.59:3000/post');
```

Then, in payment method just do

```
this.browser.on("loadstop")
.subscribe((ev: InAppBrowserEvent) => {
    // check conditions according to logic
});
```

You can simply use browser.on() if using `const browser` in constructor. And then in closeBrowser() method, `this.browser.close();` will work.

Check **[Official Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser/)**

Comment: That worked but what was the problem... Just by changing this.browser to const browser it worked whats the difference...

Comment: The in App Browser API needs it to be constant for the instance. And finally you used it in constructor or in the same previous location (inside method)? Generally const are declared at the top of class (to make it accessible at  class level)

Comment: I used it in the same location inside the payment () method... Thank you soo much