# Ionic - inappbrowser.close is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to use "in-app-browser" plugin with ionic.

Here is my code :

```
    const myBrowser = this.iab.create(mylink, '_blank');

    myBrowser.on('loadstop').subscribe(
      data => {

          if (data.url.substring(0, 37) == this.redirect_uri){
            myBrowser.close(); 
          }
      });
```

In my console, I have got this error :

```
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at InAppBrowserObject.close (vendor.js:70892)
    at SafeSubscriber._next (main.js:55)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (vendor.js:20899)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (vendor.js:20846)
    at Subscriber._next (vendor.js:20786)
    at Subscriber.next (vendor.js:20750)
    at Channel.fire (cordova.js:843)
    at InAppBrowser._eventHandler (inappbrowser.js:53)
    at cb (inappbrowser.js:118)
    at Object.callbackFromNative (cordova.js:291)
```

So, the line "myBrowser.close()" not working correctly. What is the problem ? Can you help me please ?

Comment: Check here probably what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47468086/ionic-2-cordova-inappbrowser-browser-close-is-not-a-function

Comment: Of course I tried it ... I tried to add my variable in global, initialize it in constructor, and close it but that doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I solved my problem : In my package.json, I used `'@ionic-native/in-app-browser':'5.XX.XX'` (and all other @ionic-native). But for Ionic 3, we must use `'@ionic-native/in-app-browser':'4.XX.XX'`

And of course, the imports must be like that
`import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';`

And not like this `import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser/ngx';`

Comment: So, must downgrade to 4.XX.XX? or change code to import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser'?